# WP Lazy Load Plugin Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, plugins, lazy-loading, custom-post-type

I am using a wordpress lazy load plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load/. It works for posts & pages but custom post types do not work, wondering how to apply it to custom post types? thanks

```
add_filter( 'lazyload_images_placeholder_image', 'my_custom_lazyload_placeholder_image' );
function my_custom_lazyload_placeholder_image( $image ) {
 return 'images/preloader.gif';
}
```

This is my attempt but not sure how to do:

```
add_filter( 'lazyload_images_placeholder_image', 'my_custom_lazyload_placeholder_image' );
function my_custom_lazyload_placeholder_image( $image_src, $image ) {
    $image_src = 'images/preloader.gif';
    return $image_src;
    $post_types = $post_types = array( 'post', 'video_library', 'example1_posts', 'example2_posts', 'example3_posts', 'example4_posts', 'example5_posts', 'example6_posts');
    $image->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
    return $image;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I had set my CPT images to

`$attachment = wp_get_attachment(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); 
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 650,350 ), false, '');`

I changed to the below and now it works. Seems like this plugin is not setup to support the above method of getting post thumbnail images.

`the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) );`